# Series fillColor for marker on hover ONLY

Tags: highcharts

I "faked" a clear circle as markers by setting the fillColor the same as the background. It works just fine. Now, on hover, I am trying to get the circle to fill with the series color. I can't set it as null, as then it takes the background color still.

Any ideas?

Here is my chart code (live version here:http://jsbin.com/ukabob/2/edit):

```
$(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line',
            backgroundColor: '#E9E7DC'
        },
        colors: ['#A74B59', '#46C4B7', '#EDBA70'],
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },            
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018',
                '2019', '2020', '2021', '2022'],
            gridLineWidth:1,
            gridLineColor: '#FFFFFF',
            labels: {
              style: {
                color: '#000000'
              },
              formatter: function() {
                return '<div style="font-size:22px; font-family: \'Advent Pro\', sans-serif;">'+
                    this.value +'</div>';
              },
              y:25
            },
            lineColor: '#FFFFFF',
            tickColor: '#FFFFFF',
            tickLength: 30
        },
        yAxis: {
            gridLineWidth:0,
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
              enabled: false
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            marker: {
                radius: 6,
                fillColor: '#E9E7DC',
                lineWidth: 2,
                lineColor: null, // inherit from series
                symbol: 'circle',
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        fillColor: null,
                        lineWidth: 2,
                      radius:6
                    }
                }
            },
            states: {
              hover: {
                lineWidth:4
              }
            }
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
            borderWidth:0,
            borderRadius: 0
            },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Honeywell',
            data: [700,725,750,850,950,1000,1025,1050,1050,1050]
        }, {
            name: 'Bombardier',
            data: [661,758,880,990,1065,1136,1193,1241,1289,1335]
        }, {
            name: 'Embraer',
            data: [747,789,839,861,890,908,984,1030,1097,1156]
        }]
    });
});

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how this should look like, but I see two ways:

- you want empty space between lines, and on hover fill that space, in that case you can use this solution: http://jsbin.com/ukabob/3/edit As you can see, for each series you have to set marker options:

  ```
      series: [{    
          data: [],
          marker: {
              states: {
                  hover: {
                    fillColor: yourColor
                  }
              }
          }
      }]
  ```
- you don't want empty space between lines, in that case you can set radius of marker to 0, see: http://jsbin.com/ukabob/5/edit

  ```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
          marker: {
              radius: 0,
              lineColor: null, // inherit from series
              symbol: 'circle',
              states: {
                  hover: {
                    fillColor: null,
                    fillColor: null,
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    radius: 6
                  }
              }
          }
       }
    }
  ```

Comment: That's genius !

Answer (score 3):

If you define the fillColor: "white" on the marker, on hover or select state you can't get the default/original color from the series.

I've found a way to resolve your problem. 
If you define a high value on lineWidth (>= radius), this will fill the whole dot.

```
series: [{    
  data: [],
  marker: {
    states: {
      hover: {
        fillColor: null,
        radius: 6,
        lineWidth: 6
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

Here an example: http://jsbin.com/majigera/1

A late response. Hope this can help someone.